# Busybox ash - execution with permission denied

Tags: android, shell, busybox

I'm trying to run `busybox` on an Android device, I pushed `busybox` binary to /tmp folder, then add a `i.sh` file in `/tmp` folder with code below:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo aa
/tmp/busybox dirname
```

Then enter `/tmp` folder and execute like this: `./busybox ash ./i.sh`
Error report:

> ./i.sh: line 3: /tmp/busybox: Permission denied

Device is rooted, `setenforce` has set to 0.
If use system `sh` to execute this file `sh ./i.sh`, everything is ok.

Comment: `chmod +x /tmp/busybox` ?

Comment: might be something with the path you have set for your system what does `echo $PATH` give?

Comment: `chmod +x busybox` has been set at first, If you see my words carefully, you can see that, I'm using this busybox ash to execute my script, then call this busybox again in script, if chmod is not set, this busybox can't be executed, but the script already ran to 3 line.

Comment: `echo $PATH` = `/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin`, got same $PATH result if echo from shell manually or echo in my script file.

Comment: I found other two points may need to notice. 1) It will work if move busybox to /system. 2) /tmp is symbol link to /data/local/tmp, but even in /data, it should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have root access in your Android you can copy busybox into the path `"/data/local/tmp"` and run it like `"/data/local/tmp/./busybox"`